# What happens to a bound datagramchannel when all network interfaces are down?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

What happens when I first bind a datagram channel using wildcard address using a snippet similar to the one below

```
InetAddress wildCardAddress = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(wildCardAddress, 8888);
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
                                         .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                                         .bind(isa);
```

and then all network interfaces go down and after some time some of the network interfaces go up. Will this channel still be viable or do I need to create a new one?

I am having trouble receiving multicast packets after interfaces go down and then go up again.